# Show dialog fragment in fragment issue

Tags: android, fragment, android-dialogfragment

In ViewPager, I have displayed the fragment which has custom ListView. Now I tried to display each item details of the custom list view on another dialog fragment if I clicked on any item. But I have faced the following issue

> "The method show(android.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String) in
>   the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments
>   (android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)"

I have used the `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of the `getFragmentManager()` but it does not work.

Comment: which method works when your first fragment is created getSupportFragmentManager() or getFragmentManager()  ?

Comment: ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fragmentPager);
        adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);  , I am using getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check if you're importing this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

And not this:

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
```

Comment: I have import this  import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment; one only.

Answer (score 0):

to call another `fragment` from within a `fragment` you should use `getChildFragmentManager(); //preferred` or `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: I have used both bookedDetails.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"fragment"); and getChildFragmentManager() but the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This trick may work for you make Singleton object of your Activity class like this :

```
public class YourActivityclass extends AppCompatActivity{
static YourActivityclass yourActivity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity);
yourActivity=this;

}
public static YourActivityclass getInstance(){
    return yourActivity;
}
   }
```

then to open dialogfragment on a fragment call like this :

```
date.show(YourActivityclass.getInstance().getSupportFragmentManager(), "name");
```

Comment: Where i can include that one.

Comment: Make your Activity class a Singleton class and use YourActivityclass.getInstance().getSupportFragmentManager()  in The method show(android.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String) of DialogFragment